# WooCommerce archive pages add categories before product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I should need to display categories from the product before the title in Woocommerce archives pages, like it's shown in this image. 
How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: what have you got so far?

Answer (score 5):

You can use below example to add category above the title. This function will go inside child theme functions.php or parent theme functions.php

```
/**
* @return add category link and title above the title or below the category
*
*/
function theme_slug_add_category_above_title() {
    global $product;
    echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id() );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'theme_slug_add_category_above_title', 9 );
```

You can get all the list of hooks related to product list on woocommerce/templates/content-product.php and can see the use of `wc_get_product_category_list()` in woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php

Thanks

Comment: Had the same issue. The function works and should be accepted as answer.