# WooCommerce Archive page product link not working anymore after custom snippet

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wanted to add the product category above the product title in my archive page. I've found a way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784680/woocommerce-archive-pages-add-categories-before-product-title) and I've used this code.

```
/**
* @return add category link and title above the title or below the category
*
*/
function theme_slug_add_category_above_title() {
    global $product;
    echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id() );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'theme_slug_add_category_above_title', 9 );
```

This works fine. However after adding this code the product title isn't linking anymore to the product page.
Sadly I understand almost nothing of PHP. I do understand that it's probably a wrap with the image and title that is now cut short because of the category added in between them.

The image links fine. How can I add the link back to the title as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, my first answer had an error. try the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function theme_slug_add_category_above_title() {
    global $product;

    $terms = wp_list_pluck( get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' ), 'name');
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term;
    }
    

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'theme_slug_add_category_above_title', 9 );
```

This code doesn't add the link to the category.

Comment: It works! However the category still links to the product page. If possible, it would be even better if the category links to that category archive page. Thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: I guess in that case you have to rearrange the HTML of your product item. Because it's a link inside a link. But I'm not sure if that's a good idea for SEO reasons.